# Split row in two based on date range of following row?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

So I have a view that updates based on changes in the underlying data. There are about 20 columns but most are static, there are however changes in boolean columns. Changes can be reverted in the underlying system so boolean columns can go TRUE->FALSE->TRUE  while the other columns remain the same. We are capturing the status every day (hashing and comparing) and if nothing has changed we increment the datetime field (ExportDate) to the current timestamp. If the data has changed the ExportDate stays the same and a new row is inserted with LoadDate having new current datetime. So if same boolean column value is changed again (reverted) (TRUE->FALSE->TRUE) the 3rd hash unfortunately is the same as the 1st hash and ExportDate of the 1st row is updated with current datetime - no new row is created even though it should. Is there any way for me to use the current (faulty) view and modify it to correctly show the distinct changes? The below example is for one item (chainsaw).

| Serial_No | Reserved | In_Stock | Blocked | Disposed | LoadDate | ExportDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 245586 | TRUE | TRUE | FALSE | FALSE | 2022-06-01 04:28:51.587 | 2022-06-02 02:57:00.000 |
| 245586 | FALSE | TRUE | FALSE | FALSE | 2022-06-03 04:33:05.452 | 2023-01-16 03:54:00.000 |
| 245586 | TRUE | TRUE | FALSE | FALSE | 2022-07-05 04:33:32.551 | 2022-12-22 03:53:00.000 |

So in essence, can I create a 4th row with LoadDate = 2022-12-23 hh:mm:ss.sss and ExportDate = 2023-01-16 03:54:00.000 and modify 2nd row so that LoadDate = 2022-06-03 04:33:05.452 and ExportDate = 2022-07-04 hh:mm:ss.sss? So it looks like below:

| Serial_No | Reserved | In_Stock | Blocked | Disposed | LoadDate | ExportDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 245586 | TRUE | TRUE | FALSE | FALSE | 2022-06-01 04:28:51.587 | 2022-06-02 02:57:00.000 |
| 245586 | FALSE | TRUE | FALSE | FALSE | 2022-06-03 04:33:05.452 | 2022-07-04 hh:mm:ss.sss |
| 245586 | TRUE | TRUE | FALSE | FALSE | 2022-07-05 04:33:32.551 | 2022-12-22 03:53:00.000 |
| 245586 | FALSE | TRUE | FALSE | FALSE | 2022-12-23 hh:mm:ss.sss | 2023-01-16 03:54:00.000 |

Is there any possibility to actually compare and alter data in the way that I'm looking for? I'm using Snowflake.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure I understand your situation, but when I see posts about capturing change, I wonder whether you've explored using a `STREAM` rather than trying to explore changes.  Would a `STREAM` assist your situation?

Comment: Hi - if I have understood what you are trying to do, shouldn’t you just be comparing the new record to the most recent version of the existing record?

Comment: @MikeWalton I haven't been a part of the team long enough to have been a part of designing the CDC system, but this behaviour of single boolean fields changing back and forth was not expected. This is something we will have to deal with for sure, sooner rather than later. I have not heard of `STREAM` before, could you eloborate?

Comment: @NickW yes I agree that the hash should compare the latest row with the "new" row and not all the hashes for that Serial_No (which I think is the case now). This behaviour of boolean fields changing back and forth was not expected behaviour during design so was not accounted for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit messy but using the [LEAD()](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/lead.html) and [LAG()](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/lead.html) functions you can play with the logic to pick the right dates.  Then LEAST() and COALESCE() to ensure we don't skip anything -> this part reduces readability which you can squarely blame on your source system.

For the generating a new record, I'd do this in 2 steps. 1) Fix records you have. Then 2) Write separate query to generate new row (using similar techniques) and union them together.

Nasty, nasty ... good luck :-)

[image]

```
 WITH CTE AS ( 
SELECT 245586 SERIAL_NO,    TRUE RESERVED,  TRUE INSTOCK,   FALSE BLOCKED,  FALSE DISPOSED, '2022-06-01 04:28:51.587'::TIMESTAMP LOAD_DATE, '2022-06-02 02:57:00.000'::TIMESTAMP EXPORT_DATE
UNION ALL SELECT 245586 SERIAL_NO,  FALSE RESERVED, TRUE INSTOCK,   FALSE BLOCKED,  FALSE DISPOSED, '2022-06-03 04:33:05.452'::TIMESTAMP LOAD_DATE, '2023-01-16 03:54:00.000'::TIMESTAMP EXPORT_DATE
UNION ALL SELECT 245586 SERIAL_NO,  TRUE RESERVED,  TRUE INSTOCK,   FALSE BLOCKED,  FALSE DISPOSED, '2022-07-05 04:33:32.551'::TIMESTAMP LOAD_DATE, '2022-12-22 03:53:00.000'::TIMESTAMP EXPORT_DATE)

SELECT * 
,LEAST(COALESCE(LEAD(LOAD_DATE)OVER(PARTITION BY SERIAL_NO ORDER BY LOAD_DATE),EXPORT_DATE) ,EXPORT_DATE) FIXED_EXPORT
,LAG(EXPORT_DATE)OVER(PARTITION BY SERIAL_NO ORDER BY EXPORT_DATE)
FROM CTE
```

Comment: did something very similar with LEAD() in a CTE and comparing that to the LoadDate, based on that altering ExportDate like so: lead("LoadDate") over (partition by "Serial_No" order by "ExportDate" desc) as "lead" and CASE WHEN "LoadDate" < "lead"    THEN DATEADD(DAY, -1, "lead") ELSE "ExportDate" end as "ExportDate" But this only fixes part of the problem like you said, I'll try to union in the last row or something to the above result and work from there.